# How to disable reactivity temporarily and just update/retrieve local mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Considering this requirement.

Before you publishing a new post, while editing, there is a preview panel which will render your post contents as you typing.

Because it is not a real post, we just want it will only update ( and retrieve content from)  local mongodb and do not want this post will be synced to server. 
How to implement that?

I tried this in template

```
Template.newPost.events
  'keyup .post-content' : (event, templ)->
    event.preventDefault()
    Deps.nonreactive ->
      Post.update({_id: post_id}, {content: event.currentTarget.value })
```

And this

```
Template.newPost.events
  'keyup .post-content' : (event, templ)->
    event.preventDefault()
    Meteor.call 'updatePostContent', post_id, event.currentTarget.value


Meteor.methods
  updatePostContent: (postId, value)->
    if (this.isSimulation)
      Post.update({_id: postId}, {content: value })
    else
      this.stop()
```

and all of above has no effect.

Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 6):

It would be in your helpers.

You insert the document like normal. But when viewing it you can switch reactivity on and off.

```
Template.newPost.helpers({
    yourpost:function() {
        return YourPosts.find({},{reactive: false});
    }
});
```

You pass off `reactive: false` as an option in your `find` or `findOne` query. You could use something like a `Session` to get its true or false value then change it when you need to.

Comment: Thanks, @Tarang, I will try. But I do not very understand it. As I know, when you trying to change collection by `Post.update` or `Post.insert`, it will change both server document and client document. In my requirement, I don't want server document be updated/inserted before explicitly clicking "Save" Button.

Comment: When i add in the reactive parameter, exactly as you suggested, setting it to false simply gets rid of my database results form my page - setting it back to true makes them appear again. How can it be achieved whereby you simply prevent Meteor from automatically updating?

Comment: @JoePrivett Make sure the data is on the client before you run `YourPosts.find(...)`. If you get the behaviour you're describing it means the data hasn't yet arrived on the client when you load the page hence the updates are ignored. It appears as if the initial results are empty. You can do this using `waitOn` or `wait` if you're using iron router.

Comment: How do I make sure the data is on the client? (I am not using Iron Router just yet.)

Comment: @JoePrivett you have to just wait for it to arrive after the initial page load. One way is you can use a `Session` to check against the callback from Meteor.subscribe("xx", function() {...})` to ensure the subscription is complete before you load the page.

Comment: @JoePrivett Also possible is to set `reactive: (Session.get("isreactive") || true)`. Then set `Session.get("isreactive")` to true in the callback method of the subscription, i.e `Meteor.subscribe("your_publication", function() { Session.set("isreactive", true) });`

Comment: @ Akshat This was a step in the right direction, though it is clear to me now that you cannot set the reactive: false within the template helper function. I guess this makes sense because it is telling Meteor to not do anything from the start, so of course it's not going the render these templates. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74375/discussion-between-joe-privett-and-akshat).

Answer (score 0):

You can always use an auxiliary (client-side only) collection:

```
var cache = new Meteor.Collection(null); // no-name
```

where you can play with your document while editing it and eventually copy all changes to the original collection when the user press the `save` button.